# Find the value of X that will print out sequence 1,2,...,10

Tags: python-2.7

Is this code is correct for printing the sequence 1,2,....,10 by finding value of X

```
x=0
y=1
while(y< x):
    print(y)
    y=y+1
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? Also you shouldn't still be using Python 2.

Comment: y=y+1 could be replaced with y += 1

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not correct. because y is always greater than x. So the condition will never execute. the correct code is below.

```
x=0
y=1
while (x < y) & (y <=10):
    print(y)
    y=y+1
```

If you want to print sequence on numbers 1,2,3,...and so on, remove the "& (y <=10)" from above code